# Parallel LSTM Model with shared parameters

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to build parallel LSTM models for each input feature with shared parameters. For instance, suppose I have 10 input features and I want to build a separate LSTM for each feature with shared parameters. Each feature should have their own hidden states, only parameters should be shared. I am looking to build something like this :

[Parallel LSTM Model for each input feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUKhV.jpg)

I want to do this using keras/pytorch. Any help would be appreciated.